# How to copy content of lineEdit on clipboard in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Hello Qt Programming Experts.

I'm a newbie in this area and I have started my first project. With this project, I have a `pushButton` and `lineEdit` and I want to **when I press the pushButton**, the content in `lineEdit` copies to clipboard, in other words, My problem is that I cannot read the content by pushing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QClipboard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html)

To set the text

```
void setText(const QString & text, Mode mode = Clipboard);
```

To read text

```
QString text(Mode mode = Clipboard) const
```